# How to Formulate a Pulp Objective Function with a max operator

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, integer-programming

I am trying to formulate an objective function for cost optimization in PuLP wherein the maximum of an array is added to the objective function. Please ignore the indentation.

```
#Decision Variables
allocation_vars = LpVariable.dicts(
    'Allocation',
    [(i,j,k) for i in TruckTypes for j in Days for k in RS],
    0,
    LpInteger
)

#Objective Function
for i in TruckTypes:
    for j in Days:
        prob += max(allocation_vars[(i, j, k)] * TransCost[i][k] for k in RS)
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run the above :

```
prob += max(allocation_vars[(i, j, k)] * TransCost[i][k] for k in RS)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'LpAffineExpression' and 'LpAffineExpression'
```

Comment: `max()` is not a linear function, so this violates the requirement for a linear objective function....  you're going to have to reformulate.

Comment: Reformulation seems infeasible as per the logic of the problem. Can you suggest a python package/solver that can solve Integer Non Linear Optimization Problem such as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reformulate, as [@AirSquid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10789207/airsquid) said.

Try instead the following:

1. Create a dummy variable `m[i][j]`, add that to the objective function;

```py
m = LpVariable.dicts(
    'maxCosts',
    [(i,j) for i in TruckTypes for j in Days],
    0,
    LpInteger
)

prob += lpSum([m[i][j] for j in Days for j in TruckTypes])
```

2. Add the following constraint:

```py
for i in TruckTypes:
    for j in Days:
        for k in RS:
            prob += allocation_vars[(i,j,k)]*TransCost[i][k] <= m[i][j]
```

Supposing you have a minimisation problem, this will work exactly the same as a `max`: it will reduce `m[i][j]` as much as possible, and to reduce it more, it will try to reduce the maximum of all `allocation_vars[(i,j,k)]*TransCost[i][k]`.

Comment: Whoa! Great Logic! Should this dummy variable m[i][j] be declared as a decision variable as well? Since, its value will be decided by the solver...